# Calculate weeknumber from a date value

Tags: xml, xslt, date

Is there some simple way to calculate a Weeknumber value from a date value stored in XML?

It needs to be pure XSLT solution. I cannot use any code :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use EXSLT, there are [several date functions](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html) available.  All of them are implemented in Saxon, but if you're using MSXSL, Chris Bayes has implemented them as extension functions, which you can actually place within your transform inside an msxsl:script element.  His implementations are linked from each specific date function page.

Is [week-in-year()](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/week-in-year/index.html) the function you're looking for?

**Edit:** Per JeniT's comment, there's a [pure XSLT 1.0 template](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/week-in-year/date.week-in-year.template.xsl) available on the same site with the same functionality as week-in-year() (which she wrote, I think), which might fit your requirements better.

Comment: And if you look on that site you'll find a pure XSLT 1.0 template that will do it for you: http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/week-in-year/date.week-in-year.template.xsl

Comment: So there is.  I missed that.  Even better.

Comment: Thank you both very much. This is really nice implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Week calculation can get pretty complicated if you always want the week to start on the same day, because the first day of the year is always changing.  There's an ISO standard for calculating it, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week).

Comment: I am aware of that, but it is not required. Everyweek can start with Sunday or Monday. I just need to calculate the difference between two dates (in weeks)

Answer (score 1):

**This is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution**:

One can use the **`datetime_lib.xsl`** stylesheet module by Martin Rowlinson, which comes with the **[XSelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator)** (a nice XSLT IDE, recently made freely available on sourceforge). You will have to download and install this application, then you will find a wealth of additional libraries and samples of advanced techniques and solutions.

The **`datetime_lib.xsl`**   file can be found (for a typical installation) on:

C:\Program Files\Marrowsoft\Xselerator25\Samples\Libraries\

From this library, here is the template named "week-number":

```
<xsl:template name="week-number">
    <xsl:param name="year"/>
    <xsl:param name="month"/>
    <xsl:param name="day"/>
    <!-- or -->
    <xsl:param name="date" select="''"/>  <!-- format: yyyymmdd or yyyy-mm-dd -->
    <!-- or -->
    <xsl:param name="julian-day" select="''"/>
    <!-- trim down date -->
    <xsl:variable name="tdate" select="translate($date,'-','')"/>
    <!-- decide which params were passed -->
    <xsl:variable name="yyyy">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($date) > 0"><xsl:value-of select="substring($tdate,1,4)"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($julian-day) > 0">
                <xsl:variable name="jdate">
                    <xsl:call-template name="julian-day-to-date">
                        <xsl:with-param name="julian-day" select="$julian-day"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($jdate,1,4)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$year"/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- get the julian day number -->
    <xsl:variable name="jd">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($julian-day) > 0"><xsl:value-of select="$julian-day"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="date-to-julian-day">
                    <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$year"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="day" select="$day"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$date"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- get the julian day number for the first working day of next year -->
    <xsl:variable name="fyjd">
        <xsl:call-template name="first-day-of-year">
            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$yyyy+1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="as-julian-day" select="true()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- decide which the 'working' year for this date is -->
    <xsl:variable name="start-jd">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$jd >= $fyjd"><xsl:value-of select="$fyjd"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="date-to-julian-day">
                    <xsl:with-param name="date">
                        <xsl:call-template name="first-day-of-year">
                            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$yyyy"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- final calc output -->
    <xsl:value-of select="floor(($jd - $start-jd) div 7) + 1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a simple XSLT transformation using the"week-number" template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 
 <xsl:import href=
 "C:\Program Files\Marrowsoft\Xselerator25\Samples\Libraries\datetime_lib.xsl"/>

 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="week-number">
       <xsl:with-param name="date" select="'2008-11-16'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on any source XML document (not used), the wanted result is produced:

**46**

Hope that this time the answer was really more helpful.

Cheers,

Dimitre Novatchev.

Comment: The XSelerator link seems outdated. It doesn't seem to be freely available anymore. Other than that, great solution, should be upvoted!

Comment: @Abel, Unfortunately, the XSelerator was withdrawn by its author from sourceforge.net. If you contact him, he might provide you with a permanent license -- the product is/was still freeand I remember someone contacting him and getting the XSelerator. Please, contact me if you need to discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the XSLT Cookbook by Sal Mangano.  Interestingly enough it is available on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=su4pWUPWwuEC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=xslt%20weeknumber&source=web&ots=nBBc3DVJYU&sig=l19cpOhwd9_PqrB72b9CCZk9wUA).

The xslt 2.0 way is:

```
<xsl:function name="chkbk:calculate-week-number" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:date" />
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:integer(format-date($date,'[W]'))" />
</xsl:function>
```

For the 1.0 way, see the cookbox preview.  BTW, I simply googled xslt weeknumber to locate this.

Comment: Can you provide a sample on how two use these functions, because it seems I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Go to the link I added and do a search in this book.  There is a complete example around page 143.

Comment: The format for the date should be `'[W]'` (missing close square bracket in the above).

Comment: Thanks, I'll correct when Jeff gives us our editing ability back.

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function WeekNum_ISO8601(ByVal d As Date) As Integer ' WW e.g. 29
    Dim WN As Integer
    Dim YN As Integer = d.Year
    Dim TempDate As Date
    Dim FirstThursday As Date
    Dim MondayOfFirstWeekOfTheYear As Date
    Dim SundayOfFirstWeekOfTheYear As Date
    '
    TempDate = DateAndTime.DateSerial(YN, 1, 0)
    '
    Do
        TempDate = DateAndTime.DateSerial(YN, 1, TempDate.Day + 1)
    Loop Until TempDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday
    FirstThursday = TempDate
    '
    SundayOfFirstWeekOfTheYear = DateAndTime.DateSerial(YN, 1, FirstThursday.Day + 3)
    MondayOfFirstWeekOfTheYear = DateAndTime.DateSerial(YN, 1, FirstThursday.Day - 3)
    '
    If d < MondayOfFirstWeekOfTheYear Then
        TempDate = DateAndTime.DateSerial(YN - 1, 12, 31)
        WN = WeekNum_ISO8601(TempDate)
    End If
    '
    If d >= MondayOfFirstWeekOfTheYear And d <= SundayOfFirstWeekOfTheYear Then
        WN = 1
    End If
    '
    If d > SundayOfFirstWeekOfTheYear Then
        WN = CInt((d.DayOfYear - TempDate.Day) / 7) + 1
    End If
    '
    Return WN
End Function
Public Function YearWeek(ByVal d As Date) As String ' YYYY-WW, e.g. 2022-29
    Dim tmpDate As Date
    tmpDate = d

    If (d.Month = 1) And (d.Day < DayOfWeek.Thursday) And d.Day < 7 Then
        tmpDate = DateAndTime.DateSerial(d.Year - 1, 12, 31)
        Return tmpDate.Year.ToString & "-" & Format(WeekNum_ISO8601(tmpDate), "00")
    Else
        Return (d.Year.ToString & "-" & Format(WeekNum_ISO8601(d), "00"))
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: vb 2008 Functions which returns just weeknumer (Function WeekNum_ISO8601) as an integer or the year and the weeknumber (Function YearWeek) as a string ('YYYY-WW').

Comment: OP: "It needs to be pure XSLT solution."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I program in Visual Basic, so I know how to do it using VB.NET.  Read your XML date into a variable (let's call it *SomeDate*).  Then you construct a new date that you **know** is the beginning of the year that contains your unknown date.  Then, you let the *DateDiff* function do its work to tell you the week number.

```
Dim SomeDate As Date = ReadDateFromXML()
Dim YearStart As New Date(Year(SomeDate), 1, 1)
Dim WeekNumber As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, YearStart, SomeDate)
```

Answer (score -3):

And in C#:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
int week = date.DayOfYear / 7;
Console.WriteLine(week);
```

Comment: This is incorrect... 

Have a look here to see why:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/e38accde-7eaa-462e-95d0-5a47b7dab832/